# clone one canvas to another having trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, fabricjs

I have checked all the answers to clone existing canvas to another one. But I could not get it done.

Please check my current progress.
`http://jsfiddle.net/37n8rtdf/5/`

First canvas will be clipped to that square you see initially and content of that canvas will be added in another canvas. But I don't know it always throw `TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR: DOM Exception 171` in chrome. I am using `fabricjs` to clipping content.

Bit of help is appreciated.

Thanks

Here is code of my script:

**HTML**

```
        <textarea id="line_1"></textarea>
        <input type="button" id="render" value="Apply" />

        <input type="button" id="preview" value="preview" />


        <canvas id="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>


        <canvas id="c_new" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid red; margin: 30px;"></canvas>
```

`

**Javascript**

```
            var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
            var canvas_new = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c_new');
            var product_image = 'http://www.jail.se/hardware/digital_camera/canon/ixus_800is-powershot_sd700/images/sample_photos/sample3.jpg';
            //var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            var polygon;
            $(document).ready(function(){

            fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;


            //canvas.setDimensions({width:w,height:h});
            var center = canvas.getCenter();
            canvas.setBackgroundImage(product_image,
                canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
                    scaleX:1,
                    scaleY:1,
                    top: center.top,
                    left: center.left,
                    originX: 'center',
                    originY: 'center',
                    backgroundImageOpacity: 0,
                    backgroundImageStretch: false
            });
            canvas_new.setBackgroundImage(product_image,
                canvas_new.renderAll.bind(canvas_new), {
                    scaleX:1,
                    scaleY:1,
                    top: center.top,
                    left: center.left,
                    originX: 'center',
                    originY: 'center'
            });




                polygon = new fabric.Polygon([
                    {x: 0, y: 0},
                    {x: 220, y: 0},
                    {x: 220, y: 180},
                    {x: 0, y: 180} ], {
                    left: 140,
                    top: 150,
                    angle: 0,
                    fill: 'transparent',
                    stroke: '#000', strokeWidth: 1,
                    lockMovementX: true,
                    lockMovementY: true,
                    lockScalingX: true,
                    lockScalingY: true,
                    lockRotation: true,
                    hasControls: false,
                    hasBorders: false,
                    hoverCursor: 'default',
                    overflow: 'hidden'
                });
                canvas.add(polygon);
         $('#render').click(function(){ return render(); });

                $('#preview').click(function(){ return rasterize(); });


        });

        function render()
        {
            var text_val = $('#line_1').val();

            var comicSansText = new fabric.Text(text_val, {
              fontWeight: 'normal'
            });
            canvas.add(comicSansText.set({ left: 200, top: 150, angle: 0 }));
        }




          function rasterize()
          {
              var shape = canvas.item(0);
              polygon.strokeWidth=0;
              canvas.renderAll();
            //canvas.remove(shape);
            canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
                shape.render(ctx);
            };

            var ctx2    = canvas_new.getContext('2d');
            ctx2.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
          }
```

`

Comment: Posts in StackOverflow should include a minimal reproduction of the problem. Otherwise, if the link goes down, the post will have no meaning.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I have edited question. Sorry I posted in hurry.

Answer (score 0):

@WinterMute is right, you are trying to draw the Fabric object instead of the canvas element.

You fabric object seems to have two canvases embedded (`lowerCanvasEl` and `upperCanvasEl`).
So you can modify just a little bit your code to make it look like :

```
function rasterize() {
  var shape = canvas.item(0);
  polygon.strokeWidth = 0;
  canvas.renderAll();

  canvas.clipTo = function(ctx) {
    shape.render(ctx);
  };
  var ctx2 = canvas_new.getContext('2d');
  ctx2.drawImage(canvas.lowerCanvasEl, 0, 0);
  ctx2.drawImage(canvas.upperCanvasEl, 0, 0);
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37n8rtdf/6/)

Comment: @kaiodp, this is not working as per expectation. In `rasterize()`, I did clipping all layers to that polygon. And then final output will be copied on new canvas.

Comment: I don't know fabricjs enough (that's why I didn't answered before WinterMute asked me to), but `clipTo` is a method, and I suspect there are some other issues in your code that I can't dig right now. But the part of copying a canvas to an other is covered by my answer. Now, you have to make your first canvas actually clip where you want (without libary I would use `drawImage(CanvasElement, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight);` but I assume the clipTo might do it underwood.